# Expected null pointer causing an unexpected InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, concurrency

An XML file is being used as a temporary cache to store temporary values via a SOAP request (several configuration values).  Multiple threads will be using this file, so I don't want to write to the file if it has already been updated.  In the first pass through the code, I expect the cache to return null, after which the file will be updated.  However, I am getting an `InvocationTargetException` when exiting the finally block, and the program fails.  I don't understand why the null `CacheValues` object is throwing the exception.

```
public class TempCache{
     private final ReadWriteLock myLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
     private final MyCache cache = XmlCache.getInstance(); //creates singleton         
                                                           //instance, but doesn't 
                                                           //set values upon 
                                                           //initialization...

     public CacheValues getCache(){
         Lock lock = myLock.readLock();
         CacheValues cv = null;

         try{
             lock.lock();
             cv = cache.getCacheValues();  //returns null on the first pass...

         }finally{
             lock.unlock();
         }                    // exception thrown here

         if(cv == null){
             refreshCache(); //submits SOAP request to set the xml cache values
         }

   ...
}
```

Comment: The only way a NullPointerException can be thrown here is if `cache` is null or something in `getCacheValues` throws NPE.  May need your stacktrace

Comment: Can you check the documentation to see if `getCacheValues` throws that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An InvocationTargetException happens when reflection is used, and a call is made using a `java.lang.reflect.Method`. This can happen with proxy classes or other interception, instrumenting classes.

When on the call an exception happens that is wrappend in an InvocationTargetException, and you can get the original exception with `getCause()` or looking at the stack trace.